# (Presto) SQL: Group by on columns "A" and "B" and count column "C", but also include count of "C" grouped only by "A"

Tags: sql, group-by, count, presto

*The title of the question feels a bit weird so if you can imagine a better one please feel free to help.*

Hello,

imagine a situation like this - there's a "Sales" table with 3 columns: `date`, `store` and `sale_price`, each row indicates a single item sale:

```sql
date           |  store  |  sale_price
---------------+---------+------------
2021-09-01     |   foo   |    15
2021-09-01     |   foo   |    10
2021-09-01     |   foo   |    10
2021-09-01     |   bar   |     5
2021-09-02     |   foo   |    30
2021-09-02     |   bar   |    40
2021-09-02     |   bar   |    20
etc...
```

What I'm trying to do is create a query that groups by `date` and `store`, and counts how many items have been sold by each store in each day (so, disregarding the price). So far it's very easy, but for visualization purposes, I'm also trying to add an extra row, that **per day** also includes the aggregate of sale counts.

#### Here's the end result I'm looking for:

```sql
date           |    store    |  sales_count
---------------+-------------+------------
2021-09-01     |     foo     |     3
2021-09-01     |     bar     |     1
2021-09-01     |  aggregate  |     4
2021-09-02     |     foo     |     1
2021-09-02     |     bar     |     2
2021-09-02     |  aggregate  |     3
etc...
```

I know I can create this by doing a `UNION ALL`, but it is not super efficient because it scans the original table twice:

```sql
SELECT date,
       store,
       count(sale_price) AS sales_count
  FROM sales
 GROUP BY 1, 2

 UNION ALL

SELECT date,
       'aggregate' AS store,
       count(sale_price) AS sales_count
  FROM sales
 GROUP BY 1
```

I also know that I can create an extra column using `over()` clause, and avoid scanning "sales" twice, but then I would have two different columns instead of just one like I'm looking for:

```sql
SELECT date,
       store,
       count(sale_price) AS sales_count,
       sum(count(sale_price)) over(PARTITION BY date) AS sales_per_day
  FROM sales
 GROUP BY 1, 2
```

--->

```sql
date           |    store    |  sales_count |  sales_per_day
---------------+-------------+--------------+-----------------
2021-09-01     |     foo     |      3       |        4
2021-09-01     |     bar     |      1       |        4
2021-09-02     |     foo     |      1       |        3
2021-09-02     |     bar     |      2       |        3
etc...
```

Is it even possible to achieve what I'm trying to do without scanning twice? Can the last two columns (`sales_count` and `sales_per_day`) be somehow merged?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I think you want the GROUP BY GROUPING SETS syntax. Here's a good example that is very similar to yours at a glance I think: https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-basics/sql-server-grouping-sets/

Comment: @JS interesting, I'll check it out thanks

Comment: @JS Oh my god amazing! I have been writing queries in presto for about 2 years now and I had NO IDEA this thing existed. You should make it an answer so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`GROUPING SETS`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#grouping-sets), [`CUBE`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#cube) and [`ROLLUP`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#rollup) to aggregate at a different levels within the same query. You can also use the [`GROUPING`](https://trino.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#grouping-operation) operation to determine which columns were considered in the group for a given output row:

```sql
WITH data(day, store, sale_price) AS (
    VALUES
        (DATE '2021-09-01', 'foo', 15),
        (DATE '2021-09-01', 'foo', 10),
        (DATE '2021-09-01', 'foo', 10),
        (DATE '2021-09-01', 'bar',  5),
        (DATE '2021-09-02', 'foo', 30),
        (DATE '2021-09-02', 'bar', 40),
        (DATE '2021-09-02', 'bar', 20)
)
SELECT day,
    if(grouping(store) = 1, '<aggregate>', store),
    count(sale_price) as sales_count
FROM data
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ((day), (day, store))
ORDER BY day, grouping(store)
```